# Excel macros and regular expression

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I have a column in excel sheet which contains some data. I want to write a macros to replace the cell content with the words which appears before a word with special character.
For example:

Cell content:

```
M.Ramalingam                  S/o Mahalingam
```

Should be replaced by:

```
M.Ramalingam
```

Cell content:

```
Balkis Beevi                      W-o Mahamed Ali Jinna
```

Shoud be replaced by:

```
Balkis Beevi
```

Comment: I see in one case, your special character is `.`, in the other it's the second space? How do you determine which string has which special character to look for?

Comment: In first case special character is '/' and in second case it is '-'. I am not considering '.' as a special character. All the **word** before a word with special character is to be captured

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
Function StrNew(strIn As String) As String
Dim objRegexp As Object
Set objRegexp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegexp
    .Pattern = "^(.+)\b.+[\-\/].*?$"
    StrNew = .Replace(strIn, "$1")
End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a custom formula:

```
Function CHANGE(text As String, char As String)
    Dim sArray() As String

    sArray() = Split(text, char)

    CHANGE = Trim(sArray(0))
End Function
```

Then you can use it this way in the cells:
"=CHANGE(B2;"S/o")"
The first parameter is the cell with the text you want to split and the second one is the special character.

I hope this helps you...